# How to invoke python function in a script on a remote machine

Tags: python, ubuntu

I have a python script on a remote ubuntu machine 'script1.py' which has a function 'remote_func'.

```
script1.py

def remote_func():
    return True
```

I want to call the function 'remote_func' from the 'script1.py' from a script in my local machine. Something like this:

```
from script1 import remote_func

if condition is True:
    remote_func()
```

I know the usual import statement won't work here. So what can be the solution to this ?

Comment: You will need to create a SSH connection on that remote pc, traverse through the appropriate directory and then run the function. Unless you have direct access to the pc, it will be considered illegal.

Comment: @O.o that is a manual process. I want to call that function in my script in local machine every time a condition is true. And yes, i have access to the machine

Comment: Just copy `script1.py` to your local machine.

Comment: @NilsWerner I would've done that but I want to execute the function on the remote machine

Comment: In that case you need an API in your remote machine, or a sockets connection.

Comment: @Ronnie, as eqperes has mentioned, socket connection would be lot faster.